# Appearance messed up Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, themes, appearance

Well, it seems that I've updated smth wrong and now I can't customize the appearance of Ubuntu. Everything works and looks ok with defaults, if I choose anything else the result is like on the pictures.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Have you tried to set one of the default themes (ambience, radiance) via Appearance settings?

Comment: @xangua Adwaita and High contrast worked well, there was no problem. I didn't try ambiance, not sure I still have it

Comment: @NotAstronaut How did you install Flatabulous?

Comment: @NotAstronaut I've added an answer. Check the answer and let me know if that works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you're using an old incompatible theme with your updated Ubuntu.

Since, from your screenshot, you're trying to use Arc theme and Arc Flatabulous theme, I suggest to update them.

You can get the updated Arc themes and many others from [Noobslab Theme PPA](https://launchpad.net/~noobslab/+archive/ubuntu/themes). Add the PPA using these commands

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:noobslab/themes
sudo apt-get update
```

Install the themes using these commands

```
sudo apt-get install arc-flatabulous-theme
sudo apt-get install arc-theme
```